# Bootstrap Glyphicons do not load in node-webkit

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, node-webkit

I am using node-webkit v0.10.2.

When I attempt use one inside a Bootstrap button, I get this in the inspector:

`Failed to load resource file:///blahblah/lib/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff`

`Failed to load resource file:///blahblah/lib/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf`

`Failed to load resource file:///blahblah/lib/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular`

I have included the Bootstrap CSS inside my HTML as usual. Rest of the CSS seems to work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me a little bit of code? Also, if you are trying to load things like a CDN: //path/to/domain/file.js will not work. Node-webkit loads file as system files. To use a cdn, you will have to prefix with http:// or https://

Comment: I have a downloaded copy of the Bootstrap .js and .css, which I include in the HTML page. Both work fine. The CSS includes the Glyphicons, doesn't it?